# OpenGL, how to rotate objects independent of each other?

Tags: c++, opengl, rotation, glut

My code so far

```
void display ( void )
{
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // Clear Screen And Depth Buffer
glLoadIdentity();
gluLookAt(  camera[0][0],       camera[0][1],       camera[0][2],
            camera[1][0],       camera[1][1],       camera[1][2],
            camera[2][0],       camera[2][1],       camera[2][2]            );          //Set the point looking at


glRotatef(cubeRot[0], 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);    //rotate on x axis
glRotatef(cubeRot[1], 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);    //rotate on y axis
glRotatef(cubeRot[2], 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);    //rotate on z axis

switch ( Rendermode ) { //different render mode

    case 'f':
            //Draw object I want to rotate
    break;

    case 'v':
            //Draw object I want to rotate          
    break;

    case 'e':
            //Draw object I want to rotate
    break;

glLoadIdentity();

}

//Draw object I DO NOT want to rotate

glutSwapBuffers ( ); // Swap The Buffers To Not Be Left With A Clear Screen
}
```

However at the moment all my objects rotate at the same time, how can I rotate the object I've noted to want to rotate while leaving the ones I've noted to not want to rotate still?

Answer (score 2):

Encapsulate the linear transformations with gl**Push/Pop**Matrix() and draw the object. These functions save/restore the current state of the matrix, so they don't affect other drawings.

```
glPushMatrix();
glRotatef(...); 
// glTranslatef(...), 
//glScalef(...);
drawObject1();
glPopMatrix();

glPushMatrix();
glRotatef(...); 
// glTranslatef(...), 
//glScalef(...);
drawObject2();
glPopMatrix();
```

Comment: I've put the glPush and glPop around the drawing of the objects I wanted to rotate but the other object is still rotating with them. Would you mind C&P my code and put them in the right place?

Comment: Right now I see 3 calls to `glRotatef()` in your code that take `cubeRot` as argument. If you want to execute each one of them on a separate object, don't execute these calls all at once, and most definitely not before `switch/case`. Wrap each call around it's own push/pop operation along with the method call to draw that specific object.

Comment: By the way, remove `glLoadIdentity()` at the end of `switch`. There's no need for it.

Comment: The 3 glRotate calls rotate the objects on the x, y, and z axis respectively. I want these rotations to take effect on all 3 objects in the switch/case but not on the object drawn at the end.

Comment: Oh I see. Now its clear what you want to do. Take a look at Cagkan Toptas answer.

Answer (score 2):

As @karlphillip states you need to put your rotation in to glPush/glPop matrix encapsulation. I think this code should work :

```
void display ( void )
{
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // Clear Screen And Depth Buffer
glLoadIdentity();
gluLookAt(  camera[0][0],       camera[0][1],       camera[0][2],
            camera[1][0],       camera[1][1],       camera[1][2],
            camera[2][0],       camera[2][1],       camera[2][2]            );          //Set the point looking at

glPushMatrix();  //-------------------- Encapsulate Rotation ----------------
glRotatef(cubeRot[0], 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);    //rotate on x axis
glRotatef(cubeRot[1], 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);    //rotate on y axis
glRotatef(cubeRot[2], 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);    //rotate on z axis

switch ( Rendermode ) { //different render mode

    case 'f':
            //Draw object I want to rotate
    break;

    case 'v':
            //Draw object I want to rotate          
    break;

    case 'e':
            //Draw object I want to rotate
    break;   
}
glPopMatrix(); //------------------- Encapsulate Rotation Ends -------

//Draw object I DO NOT want to rotate

glutSwapBuffers ( ); // Swap The Buffers To Not Be Left With A Clear Screen
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I thought I had put them there but it wasn't working so obviously I hadn't