# Understanding OpenGL glPushMatrix and glPopMatrix

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-compat

I'm new to OpenGL and trying to render two objects, but only one of them should rotate. I learned from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26946327) that I can use `glPushMatrix` and `glPopMatrix` to apply the roration on only one object, but mine does not work.

Here are my codes:

```cpp
void renderObjs() {
    //glPushMatrix();
    drawPyramid(0, 0.7, 0, 0.289, 0, 0.167, -0.289, 0, 0.167, 0, 0, -0.33); // a function to draw triangles
    //glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();
    glRotatef(0.3f, 1.f, 1.f, 1.f);
    drawPyramid(0 - 0.5, 0.7 - 0.5, 0 - 0.5, 0.289 - 0.5, 0 - 0.5, 0.167 - 0.5, -0.289 - 0.5, 0 - 0.5, 0.167 - 0.5, 0 - 0.5, 0 - 0.5, -0.33 - 0.5);
    glPopMatrix();
}

int main() {
    // some initialization
    ...codes here...

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

        renderObjs();

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);                      
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    // other useful functions
    ...codes here...
}
```

But neither of my pyramids rotates. Why is this happening? Am I using the `glPushMatrix` and `glPopMatrix` in the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix transformation operations like `glRotatef`, specify a matrix and multiply the current matrix by the new matrix. `glPushMatrix` pushes the current matrix onto the matrix stack. `glPopMatrix` pops a matrix from the matrix stack and sets the current matrix through the popped matrix. The unit of the angle of [`glRotate`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glRotate.xml) is degrees:

```cpp
glPushMatrix();
glRotatef(30.0f, 1.f, 1.f, 1.f);
drawPyramid(0 - 0.5, 0.7 - 0.5, 0 - 0.5, 0.289 - 0.5, 0 - 0.5, 0.167 - 0.5, -0.289 - 0.5, 0 - 0.5, 0.167 - 0.5, 0 - 0.5, 0 - 0.5, -0.33 - 0.5);
glPopMatrix();
```

---

If you want to rotate the object continuously, you need to increase the rotation angle in each image:

```cpp
float angle = 0.0f;

void renderObjs() {
    //glPushMatrix();
    drawPyramid(0, 0.7, 0, 0.289, 0, 0.167, -0.289, 0, 0.167, 0, 0, -0.33); // a function to draw triangles
    //glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();
   
    glRotatef(angle, 1.f, 1.f, 1.f);
    angle += 0.1f   

    drawPyramid(0 - 0.5, 0.7 - 0.5, 0 - 0.5, 0.289 - 0.5, 0 - 0.5, 0.167 - 0.5, -0.289 - 0.5, 0 - 0.5, 0.167 - 0.5, 0 - 0.5, 0 - 0.5, -0.33 - 0.5);
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

Comment: Yeah this is such a stupid mistake :( But I have fixed this and they are not moving

Comment: Sorry about that... I just wanted to make sure I only present one problem at one time. Still, your new answer solved my problem, and thank you very much!